# Regular Expression to switch values

Tags: regex

The following regular expression I use in notepad works on almost all lines, but a few and I can't get it to work.

```
Assert.Equal(false, General.CashFactor.IsHighlighted());
Assert.Equal(values, General.CashFactor.GetValue());
Assert.Equal(int.Parse(General.Time.Hour.GetValue()), this.GetLocalTimeEN(int.Parse(timezone.Timezone2.Zeitverschiebung), int.Parse(hour)));
```

This are 3 lines, the first and second work with the regex, but the 3rd doesn't, its output is always:

```
Assert.Equal(int.Parse(hour)), int.Parse(General.Time.Hour.GetValue()), this.GetLocalTimeEN(int.Parse(timezone.Timezone2.Zeitverschiebung)));
```

Here are the 2 commands I use for

search: `Assert.Equal\((.*), (.*)(\);)`

replace: `Assert.Equal\($2, $1\)`

Now what I would need is a command that makes `$1` only up to the first `,` and `$2` all the rest up to the `);`

Would appreciate the help, I'm sure I'm very close, but I just can't get it to work

Comment: So, `Assert\.Equal\((.*?), (.*)\);`? Or `Assert\.Equal\(([^,]*), (.*)\);`. You forgot to specify the expected output. You should also escape the `.`. See [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zE9kN4/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using a recursive pattern (to handle nested parenthesis):

search:

```
\bAssert\.Equal\(\K\h*((?(R)[^()]*(?:\((?1)\)[^()]*)*|[^,()]*(?:\((?1)\)[^(),]*)*))\h*,\h*((?1))\h*(?=\))
```

replacement:

```
\2, \1
```

details:

```
\bAssert\.Equal\(\K
\h*
(     # first capturing group
    (?(R) # if you are in a recursion (inside parenthesis), commas are allowed
        [^()]*  (?: \( (?1) \) [^()]*  )*
      |   # otherwise not
        [^,()]* (?: \( (?1) \) [^(),]* )*
    )
)
\h*,\h*
((?1)) # second capturing group (the same than the first)
\h*(?=\))
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/sP3tT8/1)

Comment: didn't even know how complicated regex can look :) - In the demo it works, but when i try this in notepad it doesn't, do you know why by any chance?